# How can I find the sum of the elements within a ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

How can I find the sum of the elements within a ListBox. I just need to find a way to store the sum of the values of the ListBox and output once the users inserts the wrong input

```
 private void theMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {


        // YesButton Clicked! Let's hide our InputBox and handle the input text.
        InputBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        // Do something with the Input
        String input = InputTextBox.Text;
        int result = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
        {
            MyListBox.Items.Add(result); // Add Input to our ListBox.
        }
        else {
            String[]arr = new String[3];
            // I just want to be able to output the sum of the elements of the ListBox (MyListBox)
            for ( i = 0; i < MyListBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
              //MyListBox.Items[i].ToString();

                MyListBox.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString();

            }
             sum.ToString();
             MessageBox.Show("Sum is: " +MyListBox.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString());

        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "when users enter anything else but a number the app shows the sum of the items entered so far "

Comment: Is it like if I have added text 124E, it should show me 7?

Comment: are you getting error in this?

Comment: I just updaloded all my code (cs and xaml). Basically the way it works is that this app takes user's input and put them into the ListBox, but for example if I enter 3RD the MessageShow should pop up showing the sum of the elements from the ListBox. Please help me solving that issue :(. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @MandarJogalekar Yes the error I get says: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.

Comment: for 3RD , what is the expected sum of the elements ?

Comment: you want to consider ASCII for character values?

Comment: @Nikita, when you run  the program you will see that after clicking onClick to add coin you will see a little window asking for integer number. So let's say you enter 3 and then 4, and then 13, but if you enter 3RD I want the sum of the previous values to be shown . Please help me solving that issue :(. The error I get says:  Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem

Comment: remove the cast since the items are string already

Comment: How? I have tried that already but it's not working :(

Comment: you can try inside your for loop

sum+=int.Parse(myListBox.Items[i].Content.ToString())

Comment: instead of x, try to use x.content.ToString()

Comment: @MandarJogalekar I have tried that too but doesn't  seem to be working either...

Comment: could you comment casting statement inside for loop and put above one which i stated, and see what error you get?

Comment: @Nikita I did what you said but still not working...

Comment: let me try it out & get back to you.

Comment: @MandarJogalekar If I do what you said : sum += int.Parse(MyListBox.Items[i].Content.ToString()); The word content get highlighted and it says: 'object doen'st contain a definition' for content

Comment: @Nikita sounds good...

Comment: Done ! you can check the answer

Comment: @Nikita Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me , try this :

```
private void YesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      int sum = 0;
      int i = 0;
      // YesButton Clicked! Let's hide our InputBox and handle the input text.
      InputBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

    // Do something with the Input
    String input = InputTextBox.Text;
    int result = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
    {
        MyListBox.Items.Add(result); // Add Input to our ListBox.
    }
    else 
    {
       sum = MyListBox.Items.Cast<int>().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
       MessageBox.Show("Sum is: " +sum);
    }
    // Clear InputBox.
    InputTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: @Nikita While he is adding integer values to listbox, we don't need the casts that I mentioned before (`Cast<object> and Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x))`) anymore and its enough to `Cast<int>` like what I did in the answer below. You may kindly find it helpful:)

Comment: You are welcome, You may kindly want to vote up my answer like a sportsman ;)

Comment: @RezaAghaei yup...just did :) ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem of your code is here:

```
MyListBox.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>
```

To calculate sum of items of your list box, if you are sure that they are integer numbers that added as int or string, you can use this snippet:

```
var sum= this.ListBox1.Items.Cast<object>()
    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
    .Sum();
MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
```

The above code assumes that you add items to ListBox using such code:

```
var value= this.TextBox1.text;
//your logic for null checking and ...
this.ListBox1.Items.Add(value);
```

Here is the complete code that I test based on your codes.

While you are adding integer values to listbox, we don't need `Cast<object>` and `Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x))` anymore and its enough to `Cast<int>` like below:

```
String input = InputTextBox.Text;
int result = 0;
if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
{
    MyListBox.Items.Add(result);
}
else
{
    var sum = this.MyListBox.Items.Cast<int>().Sum();
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sum is: {0}", sum));
    sum.ToString();
}
InputTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
```

Comment: @programadorxpert please post update code, then I'll check it :) here it works fine.

Comment: I posted a cleaner edit to @RezaAghaei's code snippet above, but basically, it should work. It should replace the entire contents of your `else` block.

Comment: I just updated my code. Once you run it , you will see the button "Click to add coins", then after clicking on it you will be asked to enter values (numbers), so lets say you enter 2, and then 3, and then 7, and finally you enter 4FG what you suppose to see is the pop up window showing the sum of the previous numbers that's all. Please let me see everything you did inside the YesButton_Click method. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @programadorxpert You are welcome:) but it seems you accepted another answer? :)